# How not to display subtotals in matrix with blank values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am using a measure not to display column subtotals. it works fine if I dont have any blanks.

```
Bond Count w/o = 
VAR Bonds = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(fact_Premium[PolicyNumber]))


RETURN 
    IF(
    NOT(HASONEVALUE(dim_Date[Year])) &&  HASONEVALUE(dim_Date[Month]),
    BLANK(),
    Bonds
)
//HASONEVALUE returns TRUE when there is only one value in specified column
```

But in this case my matrix have blanks  for particular months,  and due to that measure doesnt work. So it brings subtotals for each column.

[image]

Is any way somehow to modify it so the logic would work for cases like that?

Thank you

.pbix can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9xmpx6t997aqg9/TestBI.pbix?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I have created a table with random data posted at the end of the post, where **premium** is the column with numbers.

The calculation below has two nested IF. The first forces a column subtotal using SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Year]). The second nested IF only consider the sum of **premium** when is equal to the **grand total**.

```
Sum_Premium = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Year]),SUM('Table'[Premium]),if(sum('Table'[Premium])=CALCULATE(sum('Table'[Premium]),all('Table')),sum('Table'[Premium]),BLANK()))
```

[image: The result]

**Table**

```
+------+-------+---------+
| Year | Month | Premium |
+------+-------+---------+
| 2017 | Jan   |      10 |
| 2017 | Feb   |     349 |
| 2017 | Mar   |     406 |
| 2017 | Apr   |     350 |
| 2017 | May   |      31 |
| 2017 | Jun   |     151 |
| 2017 | Jul   |     266 |
| 2017 | Aug   |     393 |
| 2017 | Sep   |     278 |
| 2017 | Oct   |     395 |
| 2017 | Nov   |     119 |
| 2017 | Dec   |     130 |
| 2018 | Jan   |     190 |
| 2018 | Feb   |     107 |
| 2018 | Mar   |     248 |
| 2018 | Apr   |      60 |
| 2018 | May   |     302 |
| 2018 | Jun   |      23 |
| 2018 | Jul   |     248 |
| 2018 | Aug   |     347 |
| 2018 | Sep   |      31 |
| 2018 | Oct   |     218 |
| 2018 | Nov   |     326 |
| 2018 | Dec   |     251 |
| 2019 | Jan   |     173 |
| 2019 | Feb   |      86 |
| 2019 | Mar   |      29 |
| 2019 | Apr   |      68 |
| 2019 | May   |      19 |
| 2019 | Jun   |     189 |
| 2019 | Jul   |     261 |
| 2019 | Aug   |     229 |
| 2019 | Sep   |     338 |
| 2019 | Oct   |     407 |
| 2019 | Nov   |     409 |
| 2019 | Dec   |     296 |
+------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to keep the grand total

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into it. Meanwhile I posted .pbix file with proper data